# Save multiple different rtsp streams with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I can record rtsp stream to a single file as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://5.63.151.4:443/atv/atv2 c:\atv.flv
```

How can i record two or more rtsp streams to seperated files such as stream 1 to file 1 and stream 2 to file 2 by one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://5.63.151.4:443/atv/atv2 -map 0 c:\atv.flv -i rtsp://live.sabah.com.tr:443/ahaber/ahaber3 -map 1 c:\ahaber.flv
```